# iOS client application design

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating a client application for a website.

When the user open the app, the app checks if is already logged or not.

I use `AFNetworking` for making the asynchronous request and get the logged status.

Because of the asynchronous request I need to show something while the request is loading.

I thought to display a view identical to the loading view with `Default.png` image and after the request is completed push a new view relying if the user is logged or not.

I think this is a typical scenario for internet apps like client for website, what do you think about? What was your way to design the first step of the iOS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's what I do. I have a loading view that I set as my `rootViewController` when my app launches. I took a screenshot of the loading view and set that to my Default.png. Once the loading is done, I animate a transition to a new `rootViewController`.

This is a very common approach. I've used countless apps that do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you do this also in `UITabBarController` based app? How you handle this? You set the tabbarcontroller as the root view and present modal view controller with the loading screen? Also, you use AFNetworking?

Comment: I use it in a navigation based app. But that's not really relevant. The my applicationDidFinishLaunching I just set my loading view controller as the `rootViewController`. I do all my loading in my loading view controller, then when it's done, I just change the `rootViewController` of the window. I don't present it as a modal view. And I do not use AFNetworking.